# Search form with checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to create a form that finds products with checkboxes. I think the problem lies in the fact that im not passing an array to my controller. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Model

```
def self.search(params)
  arel = order('created_at DESC') # note: default is all, just sorted
  arel = arel.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%").order('created_at DESC') if params[:search].present?
  arel
end
```

Controller

```
def index
  @products = Product.search(params)
end
```

View

```
<%= form_tag(products_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do %>
<%= check_box_tag :search, "product1", nil %>
<%= check_box_tag :search, "product2", nil %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the search works, but when i tap both checkboxes i only get one result.

Answer (score 0):

Both checkboxes are the same `:search` so only the last checked one is being sent. Try something like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "search[]", "product1" %>
<%= check_box_tag "search[]", "product2" %>
```

Comment: Yes then it should be saved into an array. However, the checkbox doesnt show any results at all when i change it into search[].